# Переход к работе на Java

Tags: delphi, java

Начал работать с java. Использую NetBeans 7 и MySQL. Есть следующие вопросы, ответы на которые я бы хотел получить.

1. Как называется настольное приложение в Java?
2. Как называется форма (окно) модуля проекта в Java?
3. Как называются визуальные компоненты (VCL) в Java?
4. Какие есть компоненты и способы подключения к базе данных?
5. С какими компонентами можно отображать наборы данных?
6. Как подключиться к COM серверам вроде MS Excel?

Comment: Swing, jbdc, почитали бы вы книжечку какую-то для  начала... А то такие задачи - такими вопросам они не решаются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал забыть все что вы знаете из делфи и начать Джаву с нуля.

Или воспользуетесь JBuilder внешний вид его похож на делфи легче понять что где лежит )). Но последний его релиз был насколько я помню в 2007 или 2008.

Более конкретные ответы на все ваши вопросы зависят от IDE и библиотек джава которое вы выберите для работы.
В NetBeans есть только наборы классов часть из них доступна из вкладки Palette похоже на VCL.

Для подключения к базам есть JDBC сравнимо с ODBC драйверами.

Comment: данное утверждение "Для подключения к базам есть JDBC сравнимо с ODBC драйверами." - не совсем верно. на сколько мне известно JDBC это имплементация/реализация интерфейса ODBC.

Comment: Может немного неправильно выразился но JDBC (англ. Java DataBase Connectivity — соединение с базами данных на Java) ,а ODBC (англ. Open Database Connectivity) Принцип работы у нах тотже самый но никак не реализация.

Хотя есть и реализация интерфейса ODBC называется "Мост JDBC-ODBC". 

[вот подробное описание][1] 


  [1]: http://www.javaportal.ru/java/tutorial/tutorialJDBC/intro.html#1005731

Answer (score 2):

**Как называется настольное приложение в Java?**
десктопное приложение от консольного ничем не отличается, - только используемыми классами.

**Как называется форма (окно) модуля проекта в Java?**
JFrame, - основной компонент для разработки GUI интерфейса.

**Как называются визуальные компоненты (VCL) в Java?**
если под визуальными компонентами подразумеваются банальные элементы интерфейса, то их о них вы можете почитать в документации о Swing (классы находятся в пакете javax.swing). Если же вопрос стоит о сложных компонентах которые позволяют выполнять специализированные действия (напр. контрол для отображения данных полученых из СУБД), то в java таких нет. Вы сами вольны реализовать любой из них, именно так как вам это необходимо.

**Какие есть компоненты и способы подключения к базе данных?**
[[@Gorets](/users/3608/gorets)](/users/3608/gorets) правильно заметил, самый простой вариант это jdbc. хотя в вашем случае имеет смысл посмотреть в сторону каких-то простых ORM фреймворков (позволяют сократить количество кода связанного с взаимодействием с СУБД): ibatis, hibernate. так как вы начинаете с нуля вполне вероятно что разобратся с ними будет проще, по крайней мере поддержывать точно.

**С какими компонентами можно отображать наборы данных?**
JTable - компонента используется для отображения табличных данных. вам придется реализовать нужный в отдельном классе, который будет следить за правильным поведением и отображением данных.

**Как подключиться к COM серверам вроде MS Excel?**
в этом конкретном случае: есть бесплатные библиотеки, которые предоставляют готовый функционал, напр: Apache POI

p.s. отличия между java и delphi достаточно существенны. в java нет такого большого набора готовых компонентов, но есть очень большое количество бесплатных библиотек которые предоставляют нужный функционал. кроме того большинство из них имеют открытый код. при необходимости можно будет подстмотреть нужное прямо в коде.

p.s.s кроме того "из под коробки" у вас нет возможности создавать и конфигурировать "окно" приложения как это делается в delphi. в java весь GUI нужно закодить. хотя есть конечно варианты (фреймворки) которые облегчают эту задачу